# how do i access max and can use it in my function?

Tags: javascript, html

So at the moment in my checkMaxinput function i wrote my max value was 15 and 100 in backend-benutzer and app-benutzer.
I want the max value to replace it so i dont have to write it manually everytime the max value changes how would i do that? i tried this.max but it didnt work how do i access the max value and can implement that in my function?

```js
var percent = 1; //Standardvalue for yearly
var percentmonthly = 1.2 //Standardvalue for monthly

//diese funktion wird ausgelöst wenn das html-dokument vollstaendig geladen wird
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {

  var updatecolor = document.querySelectorAll('.updatecolor');
  //anzeige der farbe im range slider
  document.querySelectorAll(".updatecolor").forEach(updateinputs =>
    updateinputs.addEventListener("input", function () {
      var percent = calcPercent(this.value, this.min, this.max);
      const bg = getComputedStyle(this).getPropertyValue('--background');
      const slider = getComputedStyle(this).getPropertyValue('--slider');
      var colorchanger = this.getAttribute('rangecolorid');
      var sliderselect = document.querySelector('#' + colorchanger);
      sliderselect.setAttribute(
        'style',
        ` background:linear-gradient(to right,${slider},${slider} ${percent}%,${bg} ${percent}%) `
      )
    })
  );

  //Initiale Anzeige der Daten
  calcSum();
  
  
});
//hides when app-benutzer or bürosoftware-benutzer is at 100%
function checkMaxInput(element) {
  var hidden = document.getElementById('hiddenMax');
  if (hidden) {
    this.value == this.max ? (hidden.style.visibility = 'visible') : (hidden.style.visibility = 'hidden')
  }
}

//funktion damit der Slider sich beim eingeben vom input field bewegt
function updateUser(val, inputtype) {
  if (inputtype == 'Appuserrangecolor') {
    document.getElementById('AppInput').value = val;
  }
  if (inputtype == 'AppInput') {
    document.getElementById('Appuserrangecolor').value = val;
  }
  if (inputtype == 'Backendrangecolor') {
    document.getElementById('BackendInput').value = val;
  }
  if (inputtype == 'BackendInput') {
    document.getElementById('Backendrangecolor').value = val;
  }
  calcSum();
  checkMaxInput();
}

//Calculates the percentage of the currentval with the base of a min and max value
function calcPercent(curval, min, max) {
  return ((curval - min) / (max - min)) * 100;
}

//Rechnung für die Anzahl von Backend und App-Benutzern
function calcSum() {

}

function checkMaxInput() {
  var hidden = document.getElementById("hiddenMax");
  if (
    document.getElementById("AppInput").value === "100" ||
    document.getElementById("BackendInput").value === "15"
  ) {
    hidden.style.visibility = "visible";
  } else {
    hidden.style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
}
```

```css
html, body {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

header{
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
}

body, table, select {
  font-size: 12px;
}
  

input[type=range]{
  border-radius: 32px;
  height: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid-container {
    display: grid;
  grid-template-columns:600px 250px ;
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(150px, auto);
  justify-items: stretch;
  align-items: stretch;
}
.grid-item-1 {
  align-self: start;
  justify-self: center;
}

.text-grey{
  color:grey;
}

.grid-container {
  padding: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  grid-template-columns: 250px 200px;
}

#Backendrangecolor, #Appuserrangecolor, #BackendInput, #AppInput {
  --background: rgb(96,125,139,0.33);
  --slider: #00ba7a;
  background: var(--background);
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 150px;
  
}
#Backendrangecolor, #Appuserrangecolor :-moz-range-thumb {
  background: purple;
}


.grid-item {
  padding: 20px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  color: #222;
  border: 7px solid rgba(96,125,139,0.33);
}

.grid-item:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
}

.target { 
  display: none; 
}
/* Base styling*/
body {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  max-width: 768px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 1em 0;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}


a {
  text-decoration: none;
}


}

.price-container .text {
    width: 80px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: right;
}

.price-container .value {
    width: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
}
.button {
  text-align: center;
  width: 75px;
  height: auto;
  font-size:8px;
  color:#f8f8f8 ;
  background-color: rgba(255,167,55,1);
  border: rgba(255,167,55,1);

  
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="grid-container">
      <div style="width: 270px"class="grid-item">
        <header>Preiskalkulator</header>
        <div class="slidecontainer">
          App-Benutzer: <br>
          <input id="Appuserrangecolor" value="0" type="range" rangecolorid="Appuserrangecolor" min="0" max="100" oninput="updateUser(this.value, 'Appuserrangecolor');" class='appuser updatecolor'></input>
          <input class='updatecolor' style="width: 30px;border-color: var(--form_border_color);" type="text" id="AppInput" value="0" placeholder="1-100" rangecolorid="Appuserrangecolor" min="0" max="100" oninput="this.value = this.value > 100 ? 100 : Math.abs(this.value); updateUser(this.value, 'AppInput');"><br>
          Bürosoftware-Benutzer: <br>
          <input id="Backendrangecolor" value="1" type="range" rangecolorid="Backendrangecolor" min="1" max="15" oninput="updateUser(this.value, 'Backendrangecolor'); " class='backenduser updatecolor'></input>
          <input class='updatecolor' style="width: 30px;border-color: var(--form_border_color);" type="text" id="BackendInput" rangecolorid="Backendrangecolor" value="1" min="1" max="15" placeholder="1-15" oninput="this.value = this.value > 15 ? 15 : Math.abs(this.value,); updateUser(this.value, 'BackendInput');"><br>
        </div>
      <div class="grid-item" style="width: 270px">
        <div id="hiddenMax"class="button" style="margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;margin-top: 10px;">
          <button class="button" ><a class="button" target="blank" href="https://solutions.stressfrei.de/kontakt/">Größeres Packet auf Anfrage</a></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I assume you want to get the max value of the input?

Comment: Why are you overwriting the at that point already existing function `checkMaxInput` with a different one later on?

Comment: And where are you even calling `checkMaxInput`?

Comment: @jbadminton yes

Comment: @Cbroe sorry edited it

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to know how to get the `max` value of your input.
This can be done with the function `getAttribute('max')`.
[Documentation of getAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute)

```
function checkMaxInput(element) {
  var hidden = document.getElementById('hiddenMax');
  if (hidden) {
    element.value == element.getAttribute('max') ? (hidden.style.visibility = 'visible') : (hidden.style.visibility = 'hidden')
  }
}
```